# R_plotting points in multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I have two plots and I want to add some additional lines to both plots. Is there a way in R to choose the plot (among the two) to draw the new lines?

Edit1:
Actually I have multiple plots in one window using `mfrow`

Edit2:

I have edited the the question to include the problem i faced after using `mfg`in `par()`

```
x=1:10
y=seq(10,100,10)
z=seq(100,1000,100)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))

plot(x,y)
abline(a=0,b=10,col="blue")

plot(x,z)
abline(a=0,b=100,col="blue")
```

which gives 
[image]

But when I use

```
x=1:10
y=seq(10,100,10)
z=seq(100,1000,100)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,y)
plot(x,z)

par(mfg=c(1,1))
abline(a=0,b=10,col="blue")

par(mfg=c(2,1))
abline(a=0,b=100,col="blue")
```

the result is 
[image]

**Note the false behavior of the first** `abline`

Can anyone explain the reason and a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple graphics windows open, you want to use the `dev.cur()`, `dev.next()`, `dev.set()`, `dev.list()` functions (see `?dev.cur`) to identify the current graphics device and switch among devices.

If on the other hand you have set up multiple plots within a single window via the `mfrow` or `mfcol` parameters to `par()`, you can use `par("mfg")` to query/set which plot is current.

If you use `layout`, `lattice`, `ggplot2`, or raw `grid` graphics, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker. Actually I have multiple plots in one window.

Comment: I have a problem with new lines after using `par("mfg")`. For eg if I want to add `abline(a=0,b=1)`, It just draws a horizontal line at y=0. But without `par("mfg")` it works fine. Do you have any idea what might be the reason for this false behavior?

Comment: could you edit your original question to add a reproducible example?